# Material Components Web - mdc attachTo only apply to the first element

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using Material Components Web to create a website. I have a list of button with the class `.mdc-button` and I activated it with the following line into my Javascript File.

```
window.button = new mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-button'));
```

The problem is that this only applies to the first element with the class `.mdc-button`
Why is that and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.querySelector` will always return the first instance of the element found within the DOM. You can use `document.getElementsByClassName('mdc-button')` to return a full list of classes within the DOM.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp

Perhaps something like this

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName('mdc-button');
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(x[i]);
}
```

Comment: I tried `window.button = new mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo(document.getElementsByClassName('mdc-button'));` and `window.button = new mdc.ripple.MDCRipple.attachTo($(".mdc-button"));` but it just select nothing.

Comment: You'll need to loop through the results of getElementsByClassName, check my edit

Answer (score 2):

Here is an ES6 way of doing the same thing (for anyone else reading this post):

```
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.mdc-button');
buttons.forEach(button => MDCRipple.attachTo(button));
```