# Material Design Component Text Field's Label Does Not Float To Top Left

Tags: javascript, html, css, material-design, material-components-web

I'm following the Material Design Tutorials [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-web/#0). The tutorial follows a Node JS approach and makes use of npm to install the material design components. This is fine and I get the MDC 101 project running exactly as in the tutorial. The text box label floats nicely to the top left as soon as I start entering in the text as shown at the bottom of the page [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/mdc-101-web/#2).

However, I want to use the Material Design Components in my Scala Play web service and so I inserted the CSS link and JS scripts into my webpage (code below) as described [here.](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/migrating-from-mdl.md#content-distribution-network-cdn) The HTML for my page looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Shrine (MDC Web Example App)</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://material.io/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/8.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.css">
</head>
<body>

<form action="home.html">
    <div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--box username">
        <input type="text" class="mdc-text-field__input" id="username-input" name="username" required>
        <label class="mdc-floating-label" for="username-input">Username</label>
        <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="mdc-text-field mdc-text-field--box password">
        <input type="password" class="mdc-text-field__input" id="password-input" name="password" required minlength="8">
        <label class="mdc-floating-label" for="password-input">Password</label>
        <div class="mdc-line-ripple"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <button type="button" class="mdc-button cancel">
            Cancel
        </button>
        <button class="mdc-button mdc-button--raised next">
            Next
        </button>
    </div>
</form>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/material-components-web/dist/material-components-web.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you render this in the browser, it can seen that whilst the MDC Text Fields are displayed, the labels do not float like in the tutorial example running under Node.

What am I missing here? I suspect it is something to do with some Javascript not getting activated (Javascript noob here)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to instantiate the MDC textfield component. One quick and dirty way to do that is to just add a script tag to your html with the following JavaScript.

```
<script>
  mdc.textField.MDCTextField.attachTo(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field'));
</script>
```

Comment: I stumbled across it here as well but wasn't sure how to write the JS: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md

Comment: Yeeap!, Thanks @benvc

Comment: @benvc,  additionally, in my case this solution is only working for a single element. I have a login form with 2 outlined text fields one for email and the other for password, but when I add the above javascript, only the first email field gets it label to float, but not the second one. The password field still has its label stuck inside while I type. Any reason why? My thought was tha ```.mdc-text-field``` being a class, it should have worked for all the fields having it

Comment: @CliffTheCoder - see the following question and notice the use of `querySelectorAll` and `forEach` to instantiate multiple MDC components - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45152789/material-components-web-mdc-attachto-only-apply-to-the-first-element/53632362

Comment: I got it @benvc. Thanks once again, it worked

Answer (score 2):

For future visitors who followed the official [getting started guide](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/blob/master/docs/getting-started.md#using-mdc-web-with-sass-and-es2015) to install `MDC` with `webpack`, what worked for me is simply to add initialize the TextField in the JS file bundled (as mentioned in the [docs](https://material.io/develop/web/components/input-controls/text-field/)):

```js
import {MDCTextField} from '@material/textfield';

const textField = new MDCTextField(document.querySelector('.mdc-text-field'));
```

Answer (score 0):

This Jquery is a terrible kludge that I'm not proud of, but it does work and doesn't require the import statement.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() { 
   $("#user-input").val("Player One");
   $("label[for='user-input']").addClass("mdc-floating-label--float-above");
   $("#user-input").focus();
   $("#user-input").blur();
 });
</script>
```

It sets the value, adds the class required to make the label float, and then quickly adds and removes focus to the text field, which triggers the outline code in MDC to remove the outline notch.